# How to compile zip/tar file using SSH

Tags: ssh, openssl

I am trying to run through the following instructions:
[install ssh](http://www.pantz.org/software/ssh/installsshoncentos4.html)

when I get to the line "make" in the installation for zlib (first box), the following error is returned:

> make: *** No targets specified and no
>   makefile found.  Stop.

any ideas?

### EDIT

I have downloaded the latest packages so I am using theese instructions as a guide, not with old version numbers gents. Also, I am now running into a similar error. When trying to run ./config, I am returned:

> [root@123 openssl-1.0.0]# ./config
>   -bash: ./config: /bin/sh: bad interpreter: Permission denied

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the sake of your system I hope you are not blindly following those instructions without knowing why you're typing what you're typing. Terrible bad things can and will happen to you if this is the case.

These instructions are nearly three years old: That is positively **ANCIENT**. zlib is on version 1.2.5 (mostly bug fixes). OpenSSH is now on version 5.5 and OpenSSL 1.0.0 has been released (both contain HUGE security fixes over the versions referenced in that howto).

You are probably better off using your vendor's packages rather than manually building this software: you may be a little behind, but you will have less manual tracking to do & there is less risk of accidentally following old instructions that leave you with dangerous security holes.
I would only suggest manually tracking OpenSSH/OpenSSL and their dependencies if you have a real need (an ancient system that doesn't ship with SSH and can't be replaced), and even then only if you're really willing to commit the time to track the manually installed software and patch to deal with security holes that come up in a timely fashion.

---

To directly answer your question though:
The reason you are probably having the specific problem you mention: The zlib 1.2.3 zipfile no longer exists at the URL referenced. zlib 1.2.**5** unpacks into a subdirectory rather than spewing files into the current working directory, and requires you to use autoconf (`./configure`) before you can `make`.

Comment: @voretaq7, I am following these instructions and replacing the file versions with the most updated. I have openssh 5.5p1, openssl 1.0.0 downloaded but can't seem to get this to work at all. Using ./configure only gives the following error: 
[root@123 zlib1.25]# ./configure
-bash: ./configure: No such file or directory

Comment: also - our vendor packages are outdated and they are not supplying much support. We are on a DV server and trying to become PCI compliant so we HAVE to update these software packages

Comment: Yum update gives no updates for our openSSH and says v4.3p2 is most up to date(which is absurd)

Comment: I'm not sure why this is voted up when it isn't the right answer at all. I was fully aware of outdated packages. Telling me to use ./Configure does not work as "permission denied" and I'm not sure why

Comment: I upvoted voretaq7's answer not becuase he told you to use ./configure, but becuase of the core of what he said - you really ought to be using your distribution's packages and not compiling sshd yourself.

Comment: Expound on distribution packages - the packages they/we have are outdated. In order to gain PCI Compliance, apparently you need to have near the most up to date versions and our packages are SINCERELY outdated in some cases

Comment: Your linux distribution maintains a repository of pre-compiled binary packages. You should be using these instead of compiling things yourself. What distro are you running?

Comment: If your vendor package for SSH is that out of date you are probably running an OS well past its end of support life, which means you are almost guaranteed to hit a bunch of other PCI-DSS failures related to old software or bad system defaults.  This is a case where you may want to seriously consider forklifting the entire system to a supported OS rather than putting a band-aid on this single red flag in your audit...

Comment: Also specifically in re: PCI-DSS compliance, you do not have to run the latest and greatest version of every widget to achieve compliance, though it does make life easier if you're reasonably up-to-date.  You can still be compliant while running older software by showing that any applicable security fixes have been back-ported, or that secondary controls are in place to mitigate the risk. (That particular PCI myth/bogeyman is a pet peeve of mine...)

Comment: @voretaq7 - thank you for the helpful advice. We are running CentOS 5.5 on Linux machine. For example, we were running Apache 2.2.3 - no go, had to update to 2.2.15. This rpm was not available in SEVERAL repositories so had to manually compile. There are a whole bunch more than that.